# Cannot install IRkernel with install_github(): Git not installed?

Tags: r, github, jupyter-notebook, devtools

I was trying to get R working with the Jupyter Notebook on my Windows machine. I followed the [IRkernel tutorial](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/).
However, I can't install the GitHub repository, I always get the error

`install_github("IRkernel/IRkernel")
 Downloading GitHub repo IRkernel/IRkernel@master
 Error: Git does not seem to be installed on your system.`

The devtools package (2.0.1) is installed. install_github also works for example with install_github("StatsWithR/statsr") (Coursera package) (although the devtools package is not even loaded?).

Not sure how to deal with the problem, any ideas? Is my devtools package broken?

**Update**:
Just performed a re-installation of R (deleted all packages): I still get the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thought I would chime in here. I had the exact same problem. I came across this post...https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/594 where Flying Sheep simply states to install git. So went to https://git-scm.com/ and downloaded and installed, then ran the instructions https://irkernel.github.io/installation/ and everything worked. Now using R in Jupyter Nb.

Comment: But isn't that extremely strange? Git itself is nowhere listed as a requirement, I thought that everything is piped though devtools aka install_github...?!

Comment: Installed Git, it worked! Now I am stuck with the IRkernel::installspec(), did this work for you?

Comment: had the same issue in RStudio on Windows 10. Downloading git indeed solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Here a way to overcome this problem. I have installed IRkernel with anaconda in my mac (I guess is the same on Linux and Windows) I typed:

```
conda install -c r r-irkernel
```

Then I started started R from terminal by typing:

```
R
```

Finally, I have install the kernelspec to tell Jupyter about IRkernel, with the option user=FALSE for installation in the global environment:

```
IRkernel::installspec(user=FALSE)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did you experience the same error though? Did you also install: conda install -c r r-essentials?

Comment: No I have experienced other issues. Did you have Git installed?

Comment: Actually the devtools package should provide everything necessary...that's at least what I've thought so far. It also works with other GitHub packages so it's a bit weird

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Windows 7 and found older versions of devtools package work out.
I downloaded devtools_1.13.4.tar.gz（didn't test others） from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/devtools/，and did as follows:

1. install devtools_1.13.4.tar.gz from local:

   go into R, click on Packages (at the top of the R console), then click on "Install package(s) from local zip files" and install the devtools_1.13.4.tar.gz, an ERROR message shows which dependencies are in need, for me, the message was :

   ERROR: dependencies 'httr', 'memoise', 'whisker', 'digest', 'rstudioapi', 'jsonlite', 'git2r', 'withr' are not available for package 'devtools'.
2. install these dependecies:

   ```
   install.packages(c('httr', 'memoise', 'whisker', 'digest', 'rstudioapi', 'jsonlite', 'git2r', 'withr'))
   ```
3. reinstall devtools_1.13.4.tar.gz from local;
4. execute:

   ```
   library('devtools')
   install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
   IRkernel::installspec()
   ```

If message shows up like:

```
Error in IRkernel::installspec():jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
```

run R.exe from within Anaconda prompt,and execute:

```
IRkernel::installspec()
```

and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

i combined the two of the solutions given above and that worked for me , from R console none were working, now it is working so thanks to the two above contributors.

1- go in anaconda prompt and run`conda install -c r r-irkernel`

2- Now in anaconda prompt type `R.exe`

3- now run this command `IRkernel::installspec()`

and it worked`

Answer (score 1):

**I suspect that the tutorial linked to by the OP has changed**.

I get the same error when following the IRkernel installation instructions [here](https://nteract.io/kernels/r), however:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

That's despite having Git installed.

Using the following works, though:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

(Those are similar to the instructions that now feature on [the tutorial linked to by the OP](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/).)