# Cannot get IRkernel::installspec() to work, jupyter-client not visible

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I am still in progress to get Jupyter-Notebook and R working together on Windows 10 machine. After solving the [problem with install_github()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086530/cannot-install-irkernel-with-install-github-git-not-installed) I am now facing just another issue. I am still following the official [installation guide](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/), I am stuck at step 2:

Every time I get this error - I have tried this in R GUI and RStudio, the same:

```
> IRkernel::installspec()
Error in IRkernel::installspec() : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("jupyter", c("kernelspec", "--version"), FALSE, FALSE) :
  '"jupyter"' not found
```

My attempts so far: It was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056164/jupyter-client-has-to-be-installed-but-jupyter-kernelspec-version-exited-wit) and [here](https://datadrivenperspectives.com/installing-r-on-jupyter-725a4643983b), that this could be a problem with the PATH variable setting, so I have added Anaconda to the PATH enviroment. I also installed the jupyter-client via the Anaconda console. No change so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056164/jupyter-client-has-to-be-installed-but-jupyter-kernelspec-version-exited-wit) by @Ryan, but since the question answered was actually about a Linux based system I put it here in a Windows question:

One way to overcome the problem - if adding PATH variables to the environment doesn't work - is the following:

1. If Anaconda is installed and the Jupyter-Notebook with it (should be the standard install), open up the Anaconda prompt, not the Windows command prompt or the Anaconda Navigator
2. Look up the executable of R (not Rgui or Rstudio), it should be somewhere like `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin` and copy the path
3. Paste the path into the Anaconda prompt and start R by typing `R`
4. Now execute  `IRkernel::installspec()` once again, this time there shouldn't be an error
5. Now you can start an R kernel within Jupyter-Notebook

Comment: Maybe one more step should be added before step 5... Please restart Jupyter-Notebook after executing `IRkernel::installspec()` successfully.

Answer (score 2):

If `jupyter.exe` is installed under c:\python36\sripts, run 
`"setwd("c:/python36/scripts")" on R GUI, run "IRkernel::installspec()"`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to open R in the terminal, if you changed directory where R il located type:

```
 R.exe
```

and then run:

```
 IRkernel::installspec()
```

Comment: Hi again:) Just to clarify: you mean by terminal the command prompt? As admin or as User?

Comment: I was able to start R from the command prompt but unfortunately I get the exact same error...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally figured a way out...was sort of mentioned in one of the posts I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue trying to run Jupyter Lab on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS headless server running in an Azure VM.

To resolve the issued, I had to navigate to `/usr/bin` and open R from there. It turns out that despite my path, calling `R` from the terminal opened the anaconda3 version in `/home/<you>/anaconda3/bin/R`.

Run `IRkernel::installspec()` from `/usr/bin/R` in as `sudo` and it should add the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new virtual environment for R. Either using the CLI or the anaconda Navigator (best recommended, If and if you're using Anaconda).