# How to make R to be avaible in Jupiter notebook?

Tags: r

I have Jupiter Notebook and it sees Python3 clearly. Then I installed R, installed IRkernel using this [instruction](https://dzone.com/articles/using-r-on-jupyternbspnotebook) but when I used the command

```
IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)
```

I got an error:

```
Error in IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE) : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("jupyter", c("kernelspec", "--version"), FALSE, FALSE) :
  '"jupyter"' not found
```

Please help me to understand where is the mistake?
(Windows 10, Python3)

Comment: I think this is a PATH problem. See if the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/q/53101645/10276092

Comment: Thank you @M.Viking, tried it but unsuccessful. Decided to use R Markdown in R Studio )